# Automate creation of arbitrary function name with string manipulation in tkinter sub-menu command

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter, command

I made a root window with tkinter, with menus (File, Material) and following sub-menu for File (New, Open, etc) and Material (Add, Edit). To reduce repetitiveness, to invoke sub-menu command (File - New), I tried the following code. I know the weird thing is, I try to create variable assigned to sub-menu command is of string type (as I made it from combination of Menu-Submenu, made it lowercase and replace all whitespaces). By printing it (I use x, print (x) is file_new, which should be correspond to similar name file_new). But it was not working, seems python/tkinter ignoring/nothing happen. Please advise if this can be done in python (I expect its famous flexibility). My code below

```
""" Create window with menu """
from tkinter import Tk, Menu, BOTTOM, X
from tkinter.ttk import Label
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

window = Tk()
window.title('Thermolator')
window.geometry('640x480')
window.resizable('False', 'False')

menus = ('File', 'Material')
file_fields = ('New', 'Open', 'Save', 'Save As', 'Close')
material_fields = ('Add', 'Edit')

def statusbar(text=''):
    Label(window, text=text, anchor='w').pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

def not_yet():
    showerror('Not Implemented', 'Not yet available')

def file_new():
    statusbar('New file!')

def file_open():
    statusbar('Open existing file!')

def file_save():
    statusbar('Save file!')

def file_saveas():
    statusbar('Save file as ...')

def file_close():
    statusbar('Close file!')


top = Menu(window)
window.config(menu=top)

# create menu and sub-menu with its command
for index, item in enumerate(menus):
    menu = Menu(top, tearoff=False)
    top.add_cascade(label=item, menu=menu, underline=0)
    if index == 0:
        for field in file_fields:
            x = (item + '_' + field).lower().replace(' ' , '')
            menu.add_command(label=field, command = x , underline=0)
            print(x)

    else:
        for field in material_fields:
            menu.add_command(label=field, command=not_yet, underline=0)

window.mainloop()

"""
print(x) above give these:
    file_new
    file_open
    file_save
    file_saveas
    file_close

"""
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. My point is I want to avoid literally (or explicitly) write down "file_new" but seek way for python code to construct it and reference it to function with the same name.

Comment: Replace to: `command=globals().get(x, None)`. This restricts to be your `for ...` and `def file_xxx`  in the same module.

Comment: Hi @stovfl, it works! Thank you. You as 'top 2% this year' truly means something :-)